# How can I read an hdf5 matrix using scala/breeze?

Tags: scala, hdf5, scala-breeze

I am using the Breeze library in Scala.  Is there a simple way to read an HDF5 dataset into a matrix (presumably using the Java HDF5 interface)?

Answer (score 1):

There's not, sorry. There's an open issue (https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues/42).